# WPF Form Designer has issues with my XAML. Please help

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, c#-4.0

I'm learning WPF and XAML. Here is my Form XAML code and the code for my class (ListboxMenuItem)

```
<Window x:Class="Bail.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Bail"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Closing="Window_Closing" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources> 
            <src:ListboxMenuItems x:Key="ListboxMenuItems"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="185" />
            <!-- Or Auto -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ListBox Width="150" Margin="0,5,0,10" Grid.Column="0"
                 ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListboxMenuItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ListBox>


        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here are the errors

---

after correcting the xmlns:src, I get the following
Warning:

### Warning 1   ''src' is an undeclared prefix. Line 8, position 14.' XML is not valid. C:\Bail\Bail\Bail\MainWindow.xaml   8   14  Bail

The error refers to this line in the XAML (`<src:ListboxMenuItems x:Key="ListboxMenuItems"/>`)

ListBoxMenuItems is a class I created in C#.

Here;s the code to the class

```
//FileName: ListboxMenuItems.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Bail
{
    public class ListboxMenuItem
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }

        public ListboxMenuItem(String firstName, String lastName, String address)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Address = address;
        }
    }

    class ListboxMenuItems 
    { 
        List<ListboxMenuItem> Items { get; private set; } 
        public ListboxMenuItems() 
        { 
            Items = new List<ListboxMenuItem>(); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Michael", "Anderberg", "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45")); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Chris", "Ashton", "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67")); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Cassie", "Hicks", "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89")); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Guido", "Pica", "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10")); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your xmlns declaration at the top should include src:

xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Bail"

Also, it looks like you'll need to point your ItemsSource of your ListBox to Items within your class.  I would suggest changing your class to just inherit from List and do away with the Items property:

```
class ListboxMenuItems : List<ListboxMenuItem>
{ 
    public ListboxMenuItems() 
    { 
        Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Michael", "Anderberg", "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45")); 
        Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Chris", "Ashton", "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67")); 
        Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Cassie", "Hicks", "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89")); 
        Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Guido", "Pica", "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10")); 
    } 
}
```

This should make it work.

Comment: Great catch on the ListboxMenuItems class.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
xmlns="clr-namespace:Bail"
```

must be changed to

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Bail"
```

Edit:

After making the `ListboxMenuItems` Class `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` the Code works for me:

```
//FileName: ListboxMenuItems.cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Bail
{
    public class ListboxMenuItem
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }

        public ListboxMenuItem(String firstName, String lastName, String address)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Address = address;
        }
    }

    public class ListboxMenuItems : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
    {
        List<ListboxMenuItem> Items { get; set; }

        private int _position = -1;
        public ListboxMenuItems()
        {
            Items = new List<ListboxMenuItem>();
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Michael", "Anderberg", "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45"));
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Chris", "Ashton", "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67"));
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Cassie", "Hicks", "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89"));
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Guido", "Pica", "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10"));
        }

        #region Implementation of IEnumerable

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
        /// </returns>
        /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Implementation of IEnumerator

        /// <summary>
        /// Advances the enumerator to the next element of the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the enumerator was successfully advanced to the next element; false if the enumerator has passed the end of the collection.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The collection was modified after the enumerator was created. </exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            _position++;
            return (_position < Items.Count);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the enumerator to its initial position, which is before the first element in the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The collection was modified after the enumerator was created. </exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        public void Reset()
        {
            _position = -1;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current element in the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The current element in the collection.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The enumerator is positioned before the first element of the collection or after the last element.</exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return Items.ElementAt(_position);
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello WaltiD. The issue is still in the XAML file. it doesnt like <src:ListboxMenuItem...

Comment: Restart VisualStudio, Create a new WPF Project, copy the content of the xaml into window1.xaml, add a new class, copy the content of the class.
You have this warning, but does it compile, do you see the listbox?

Answer (score 0):

`src` is not defined as a namespace prefix in your XAML file.

You probably need to change line 4 to:

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Bail"
```